# Change file creation date and time based off of file name

Tags: files, timestamps

I was copying Asterisk call recordings from our main server to a samba share and the creation date and times were changed to the current date and time.

The file format is: `in-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-20211020-162749-1634761669.7921917.wav`

The bold part is in EPOCH time.
I have hundreds of these files and I need to change the creation date of the file based on that EPOCH time stamp in the file's name.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: By *creation date*, do you mean the *last modification time* of the file (the one reported by `ls -l`)?

Comment: yes, thanks for the reply

Comment: I suspect that timestamp in the `asterisk` file name corresponds to the start of the recording. If that's the case, it may make more sense to have the *birth time* correspond to the start of the call and the *last modification time* to the end of the call.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With GNU `touch`, you can use `touch -d @1634761669.7921917 file` to set the *last modification time* of a file to the specified epoch time (even with subsecond precision as here).

So you could do in `zsh`:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
ret=0
for file in *-<->.<->.wav; do
  t=${file:r} t=${t##*-}
  touch -d @$t -- $file || ret=$?
done
exit $ret
```

If it's really the *creation time*, often called *birth time*, as reported by `ls -l --time=birth` with recent versions of GNU `ls` for instance that you want to change, AFAIK that is not possible on Linux other than changing the clock back to that time and create the file again.

---

The part below is wrong, it does *not* change the time in the namespace only as I originally believed. See [@Busindre's answer](/a/713110) for details.

If on Linux (a recent version¹), you could however only change the clock in a new `time` namespace so as not to affect the system's clock globally.

For instance, with:

```
sudo unshare --time sh -c 'date -s @1634761669.7921917 && exec cp -a file file.new'
```

You would create a `file.new` copy of `file` with a *birth time* close to `@1634761669.7921917`

```
$ sudo unshare --time sh -c 'date -s @1634761669.7921917 && exec cp -a file file.new'
$ ls -l --time=birth --time-style=+%s.%N file file.new
-rw-r--r-- 1 stephane stephane 0 1642699170.474916807 file
-rw-r--r-- 1 stephane stephane 0 1634761669.792191700 file.new
```

The `zsh` script above could then be written:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
ret=0
for file in *-<->.<->.wav; do
  t=${file:r} t=${t##*-}
  
  unshare --time sh -c '
    date -s "@$1" && exec cp -aTn -- "$2" "$2.new"' sh "$t" "$file" &&
    mv -f -- "$file.new" "$file" || ret=$?
done
exit $ret
```

(and would need to be run as `root`).

#### Some second thought while revisiting this:

I just realised that causes a potential problem: that `unshare --time` hack allows the birth time to be set to some arbitrary time in the past but that also causes the *change status time* (the one reported by `ls -lc` for instance) to be set in the past, to the specified time, plus the time it took to make the copy).

That *ctime* is not meant to be settable arbitrarily either. By setting it in the past like that, it may break the assumptions that some software may make about those files. For instance a backup software  may decide to disregard it because it has a ctime that predates the last backup time.

So it may be better to make sure the ctime is not set in that namespace with a faked clock time, for instance, by only *creating* the file in the past, but copying its contents in the present:

```
unshare --time sh -Cc '
  umask 77 && date -s "@$1" && : > "$2.new"' sh "$t" "$file" &&
  cp -aT -- "$file" "$file.new" &&
  mv -f -- "$file.new" "$file"
```

---

<sup>¹ you need a Linux kernel 5.6 or above and `CONFIG_TIME_NS` to be enabled in the kernel and `util-linux` 2.36 or above.</sup>

Comment: my version of unshare doesnt have the --time option.  unshare from util-linux 2.33.1.  I get the following message when trying to run that command. unshare: unrecognized option '--time'
Try 'unshare --help' for more information.

Comment: I was able to use the zsh and touch option you post above, Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The use of the time namespace with `unshare` is not correct. When using the `date` command to set the system date and time, a system call of type "CLOCK_REALTIME" is made.

This systemcall is not compatible with the time namespace and therefore, even if a time namespace (`unshare -T`) is used with the intention of not impacting the entire operating system, it will not work. When using unshare with the -T/--time option, the only system calls that would take effect in the new namespace would be CLOCK_MONOTONIC/BOOTTIME (example `uptime` command).

To clone the access and modification times, the -r option of touch can be used.

```
touch target_file -r reference_file
```